# How to list innerHTML of class elements to console?

Tags: javascript

been trying to list an array of names from the innerHTML of class elements to the Console using the following code...

```
var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("name"); for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { cells[i].innerHTML }
```

Which works ok but only returns the one name. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your question makes little sense because I think you've mixed up a lot of terminology. But, try `var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("name"); for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { console.log(cells[i].innerHTML) }` in case that's what you're looking for.

Comment: `console.log(cells[i].innerHTML)` — just "mentioning" `cells[i].innerHTML` won't do anything.

Comment: @ Pointy: Thank you. That worked perfectly.

Comment: Apologies to junvar. Thank you too!